# Java class property with type unknown at compile time

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a Java class with a property that can be either a String, a boolean or a List.
What would be the best approach to declare that property type? Knowing that I can only know its type at Runtime.

My first approach was to define that property with type Object, but not sure if there's a better way to achieve this.

```
private final String expression;

private Object expressionValue;

ParsedExpression(String expression, Person person) {
        this.expression= expression;
        expressionEvaluator(person);
}

private void expressionEvaluator(Person person) {
        switch (this.expression) {
        case "name":
            expressionValue = person.getName();
            break;
        case "adult":
            expressionValue = person.isAdult();
            break;
        case "addresses":
            expressionValue = person.getAddresses();
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Property does not exist on type Person");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The most specialized type of these three types is `Object`, which is a) not very helpful and b) a smell. Since Java is strongly typed, there is no easy solution for this problem. Maybe you can get around with generics. But I would consider a redesign. For this, however, we nee to know more about the semantics of your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very few types and not going to change them you can use a generic class with a private constructor and a few factory methods which allow creating an instance only with specified type parameters:

```
public final class ExpressionValue<T> {
    private final T value;

    private ExpressionValue(T value) {this.value = value;}

    public Optional<String> getAsString() {
        return (value instanceof String) ? Optional.of((String)value) : Optional.empty();
    }

    public Optional<Boolean> getAsBoolean() {
        return (value instanceof Boolean) ? Optional.of((Boolean) value) : Optional.empty();
    }

    // in this context empty collection and empty optional mean different things
    @SuppressWarnings("OptionalContainsCollection")
    public Optional<List<?>> getAsList() {
        return (value instanceof List) ? Optional.of((List<?>) value) : Optional.empty();
    }

    public void use(Consumer<? super String> stringUser, Consumer<? super Boolean> booleanUser, Consumer<? super List<?>> listUser) {
        getAsString().ifPresent(stringUser);
        getAsBoolean().ifPresent(booleanUser);
        getAsList().ifPresent(listUser);
    }

    public static ExpressionValue<String> fromString(String string) {
        return new ExpressionValue<>(string);
    }

    public static ExpressionValue<Boolean> fromBoolean(boolean bool) {
        return new ExpressionValue<>(bool);
    }

    public static ExpressionValue<List<?>> fromList(List<?> list) {
        return new ExpressionValue<>(list);
    }
}
```

---

If you have many available types or need more flexibility of types you can use a hierarchical approach. In this case, you need to create an interface with common String, boolean and List methods, and then create implementations of this interface with all available type parameters. It may look like this:

```
public interface ExpressionValue<T> {
    boolean check();
}
```

```
public abstract class ExpressionValueSkeleton<T> implements ExpressionValue<T> {
    private T value;

    public ExpressionValueSkeleton(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    protected T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

```
public class StringExpressionValue extends ExpressionValueSkeleton<String> {
    public StringExpressionValue(String value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean check() {
        return !getValue().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

```
public class BooleanExpressionValue extends ExpressionValueSkeleton<Boolean> {
    public BooleanExpressionValue(Boolean value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean check() {
        return getValue();
    }
}
```

```
public class ListExpressionValue<E> extends ExpressionValueSkeleton<List<E>> {
    public ListExpressionValue(List<E> value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean check() {
        return !getValue().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

If you want perform some operations which are available only for some types you can use [Acyclic Visitor pattern](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/acyclic-visitor/).